# vsis3 handler in qgis plugin with python

Tags: python, plugins, gdal, qgis

I am creating a raster layer inside qgis plugin with `QgsRasterLayer(layer_uri, layer_name)`, where layer_uri is a vsis3 handler of format `/vsis3/bucket/key`. How to configure aws credential for vsis3 here (I have aws credentials set as environmental variables)?

I looked into this [link](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#drivers-supporting-virtual-file-systems), where it mentioned that vsis3 has specific configuration option of AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. But how to exactly configure it? Should I include credentials as part of the layer_uri? If so, what is the uri structure? Or there are other apis that I should use to attach credential to vsis3 handler somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Environmental variables are used for it, and you also need the AWS_SESSION_TOKEN if you are assuming a role. in addition it requires that the underlying GDAL version be built against libcurl. See /vsis3/ (AWS S3 files) https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html